# xsl namespace and mapping nodes

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xlm

Trying to understand how 3rd party xsl namespace is used to reference xml data.

There are 2 xsl files used to generate html from xml and I don't see how the root node is referenced as "Datasource" as it is in these files.
The primary xsl file includes the secondary xsl file. The secondary "common" xsl file has snippets like:

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="z79">
  function GetCurrentTime()
  {
  return String(new Date());
  }
</msxsl:script>
```

Both xsl files have namespaces defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:z79="Acme.Hammer" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0">
<xsl:include href="Common\Common.xsl"/>
   <xsl:output method="html"/>
```

And the input xml file starts of as:

```
<TopData xmlns="Acme.Hammer">
    <Middle name="middleLayer">
        <Lower>
            <Characteristic  name="UNIQUEID">
                <Value>@708</Value>
                <Timestamp>2016-10-23T11:35:22</Timestamp>
            </Characteristic>
```

In the primary xsl file variables are declared:

```
<xsl:variable name="language" select="/z79:Datasource/@xml:lang"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="StartTimeCharac" select="/z79:Datasource/z79:Middle/@startTimeCharacteristic"/>
```

So z97 is a shortcut for the "Acme.Hammer" namespace. Which matches the xmlns of the root xml node 'TopData'.
But from there I'm guessing "Datasource" is mapped to the TopData node?
Does this xsl make sense?

I know it's only fragments but it is proprietary and I can't post whole files.

I've read several xsl tutorials but I haven't come across this type of configuration.

Please tell me how "Datasource" is mapped to "TopData".

Comment: We don't see the full picture here. If the XML document being processed has `TopData` as its root element, then the variables you show will end up being empty.

Comment: Apparently this is used with either a custom processor or at least one with built in definitions that relate to the namespace and strange looking xpath. I'm just going to bypass their xsl and roll my own. Thanks for looking though!